# Markov Chain and cryptanalysis

Tags: reference-request, markov-chains, cryptography

Where I will be able to found papers to read the state-art of the use
that Markov chain in **cryptanalysis**. I found this

- Canteaut, A. and Chabaud, F. (1998). A new algorithm for finding minimum-weight
  words in a linear code: Application to mceliece ́ cryptosystem and to narrow-sense
  s
  bch codes of length 511. IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, 44.
  Canteaut, A. and Sendrier, N. (1998). Cryptanalysis of the original mceliece cryptosys-
  tem. Lecture Notes in Computer Science, 1514:187–199.
- Decrypting classical cipher text using Markov chain
  monte carlo.

but I need more please

Comment: Google? MathSciNet?

Comment: If you have access to MathSciNet (or to a librarian who can access it for you), you will find 19 papers that cite the Canteaut-Chabaud paper. Also, 32 papers come up when you search MathSciNet for anywhere = markov chain & anywhere = crypt*.